# Flutter GetX State Management

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Why can I not access the id of my object within a worker of GetX?

[image]

**Here is my controller:**

```
class SelectedSecretController extends GetxController {

  Rx<Secret> selectedSecret = Secret().obs;


  void setSelectedSecret(secret) {
    selectedSecret.value = secret;
 }
}
```

**Here is my secret model:**

```
class Secret {
  String id;
  String full_name;

  Secret({this.id = "", this.full_name = ""});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason you need to explicitly specify the type of the callback parameter as of now (may be limitation of the dart generics).

So instead of this:

```
 ever(selectedSecret, (val) {
  print(val.id);
 });
```

You need to do like this:

```
 ever(selectedSecret, (Secret val) {
  print(val.id);
 });
```

Comment: You could also use `ever<Secret>(selectedSecret, (val) => print(val.id));` if you're using the `- avoid_types_on_closure_parameters` linter option